# Itemize not giving correct result. It is omitting % sign

Tags: itemize

I am creating a list of items using 'itemize'. The lines in the item have the sign "%" after a figure. The given lines are:

1. The revenue has increased by 27% YOY and that has resulted in increase of income by 15%.
2. This impact has resulted in increase of the MOM growth by 20% and WOW growth by 10%.

Now, 'itemize' is omitting everything after % sign. So the output is coming out to be:

1. The revenue has increased by 27
2. This impact has resulted in increase of the MOM growth by 20

Can someone explain why? And how do I correct this?

The code I am using is:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item The revenue has increased by 27% YOY and that has resulted in increase of income by 15%.
\item This impact has resulted in increase of the MOM growth by 20% and WOW growth by 10%.
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: `%` ist the *comment start character* You have to *escape* it by preceeding a backslash: `\%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the sign `%` signifies a comment in LaTeX files. If you'd like to write %, your code has to be: `\%`.

But please get yourself an introduction into LaTeX, otherwise you'll run into much more issues and you'll waste your time. The most usefull tip I can give you is: `texdoc »packagename«` on the commandline will usually bring up the manual of a package (at least if you installed TeXlive, don't know for MikTeX).